# Capistrano very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am not sure where exactly the problem is located but Capistrano takes about 5 minutes to deploy an almost empty project.

Can you tell me if I am doing something wrong or is it usual?

I am using:

- Capistrano 2.9.0
- Rails 3.1.3
- Github Repository
- not too slow server (4 cores, 1 GB memory)
- ngix, passenger

Here is the output I am getting:
https://gist.github.com/1632009

**Capfile**

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :user, 'rubys'
set :domain, 'example.com'
set :application, 'EXAMPLE'

# adjust if you are using RVM, remove if you are not
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
#set :rvm_type, :user

# file paths
set :repository,  "git@github.com:GITHUBREPO/ashop.git"
set :deploy_to, "/apps/#{application}"

# using a local git repository on the server you are deploying to.
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, [ '.git' ]


# distribute your applications across servers (the instructions below put them
# all on the same server, defined above as 'domain', adjust as necessary)
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true


set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, false
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, :production

namespace :deploy do
  desc "cause Passenger to initiate a restart"
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

- Networkspeed workplace: 
  http://www.speedtest.net/result/1714391142.png
- Speed Github - Server: ~ 300KiB

Comment: 5Mbit upload/download in theory http://www.speedtest.net/result/1714391142.png

Comment: maybe server <=> github is slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano is probably slow for a bunch of reasons. One is that it opens a new remote shell to your server for every `run` in your deploy.rb file.

This can be amended a bit by using ssh master channels, which will cause capistrano to actually reuse ssh connections, which means less network overhead.

Here's an article on ruby deployment that mentions ssh master channels: http://alexyoung.org/2011/05/17/deployment/

Another reason is that it copies your entire codebase to a new directory for every deploy.

This is not strictly necessary when using git, and github has a wonderful article on how to "fix" this: https://github.com/blog/470-deployment-script-spring-cleaning

Comment: With the master channels the deployment got a little bit faster. Later I will try the second solution too.

Comment: Capistrano appears to reuse its SSH connection regardless of master channel configuration in .ssh/config.

Comment: I noticed no difference when using master channels. When I manually SSH to my server concurrent connections are much faster, but Capistrano doesn't seem to care.

Comment: The master channel seems to terminate once it is closed.. I need to keep one SSH connection open for the others to be faster.. Try to open a SSH connection and then deploy @Ciryon

Comment: Actually not making a difference, each command still taking 5 seconds, and no log output on my master ssh channel, meaning its not being used by capistrano..

Comment: Note that this is a three year old answer, so it might not be a good solution anymore. It did speed things up a bit when I wrote that, in January 2012.